# Parallelogram and triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Could you please help me with this geometric task, as I cannot solve it by myself?

- Given:  On the side CD of parallelogram ABCD is given point T, and
  point R is on the segment AT.

  Find :What percent of A(ABCD) is A(BTR) if:

  A) R is in the middle of AT

  B) AR : TR = 3 : 2
  [image]
  Thank you in advnace! I'd be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Provide a diagram and your attempt to make your question more well received!!

Comment: What is $s(ABCD)$?I knew $ar(ABCD)$ which denotes area...what is $s$?

Comment: Is the position of $T$ on $CD$ not specified?

Comment: No, it is not specified.

Comment: Diagram is wrong....You have marked $T$ on $CB$ not $CD$...

Comment: Yeah, that happens when I hurry. Let me fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the formula of area of triangle and parallelogram we have:

A(ATB)=A(ABCD)/2

A(BTR)/A(ATB)=TR/TA

So A(BTR)/A(ABCD)=TR/(2TA)

So the answer for A) is 1/4 and the answer for B) is 1/5

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the answer.

Comment: Until when the first-timers of SE will put the mark of the best answer to the first one they see? One thing is "a satisfactory answer" and another thing is "the best answer" which involves  a comparison with others. Many times this mark of the best answer is put having just one answer.(This comment has nothing at all against this answer of @Momo)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but as there aren't more answers, I accept this one. :)

Comment: @SuperMan: In your case your choice is justified because you have had ocassion of comparison but lately many beginners in SE put "best answer" at the first one received (which often is clearly inferior to others received after). I think the solution to this irregularity in language can be avoided changing "best answer" by "satisfactory answer".

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

How the following triangles are related?

[image: 6triangles]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you for this picture! :)